# UIStackview constraints not applied to edges on different iPhone screen size

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

i have a UITableView that contains a prototype cell holding labels , each label subbed in a view , all views stacked in a vertical UIStackView
and i have a constrain for the stack ,,

[image: xcode design mode]

at runtime in iphone SE

[image: iPhone SE screenshot]

unless I set stack width for 414 ( for iphone 6+ ) it will appear like

[image: iPhone 6+]

i don't want to set fixed width , but the constrains not applied correctly ,, what i have missed here

Comment: share constraints of the the table ??

Answer (score 0):

Set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints of stackView equal to leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints of content view in your table view cell. Change constant of constraint how you want to.

*delete centerX and centerY constraints, you don't need them if you set it how I wrote above*

**In storyboard**

Just select stack view and click to Add New Constraint icon. Then set value of leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint and click to Add 4 Constraints

[image]

Comment: i did like described above ,, but I got same result